# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTag Error

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jstl

Actually I am making a Java MVC project, I have added taglibs.standard.impl.jar from Apache to lib of Tomcat and added it to the the Java Build Path. I tried others ways also but they were not successful and tags were not identified by the Eclipse IDE. Now although the tags had been idetified but this error comes on running the application.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTag
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1707)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1223)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at in.ciat.vidya.controller.StudentLogin.doPost(StudentLogin.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Output jsp code is as :

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="in.ciat.vidya.model.Student"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%if(session==null){
response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");

} 

ArrayList al =(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("al");

Object[] arr =al.toArray();

String[] starr={"Student Id: ", "First Name: ","Middle Name: ","Last Name: ","Sex: ","Date of Birth: ", "Address: ","City: ","State: ", "Country: ", "PIN: ","e-mail: ", "Mobile No.: ","Alternate No.: ", "Institute Id: ","Discipline: ","Semester: " ,"Password: ","Photo:" ,"Emergency Contact Name: " ,"Emergency Contact Relation: ","Emergency Contact No.: ", "Last Login Date: " };
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Profile</title>
</head>
<body>

    <c:forEach var="value" items="${arr}" varStatus="status">
        ${starr[status.count]}: ${value}
    </c:forEach> 

    City: <c:out value=”${user.address.city}” default=”N/A”/>

<%--   or u can use      Student Id: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         First Name: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Middle Name: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Last Name: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Sex: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Date of Birth: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Address: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br />  --%>
<%--         City:<c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br />  --%>
<%--         State: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Country: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         PIN: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         e-mail: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Mobile No.: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Alternate No.: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Institute Id: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Discipline: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Semester: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Password: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Photo: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Emergency Contact Name: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Emergency Contact Relation: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Emergency Contact No.: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
<%--         Last Login Date: <c:out value=”${}” default=”N/A”/><br /> --%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jstl` jar file is missing in runtime classpath.

[Download the jstl jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/), and put it in your application `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: Now this error is coming...Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The tag handler class for "c:forEach" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag) 
  was not found on the Java Build Path
 - The tag handler class for "c:forEach" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag) 
  was not found on the Java Build Path